# Reference to parent of an element in SCSS

Tags: sass

I would like this code:

```
ul li {
    ...

    &:first-child a {
        ...
    }

    &:last-child a {
        ...
    }

    &.active a {
        ...
    }

    a {
        ...
    }
}
```

to be like this:

```
ul li {
    ...
   
    a {
        ...

        &:first-child a ...
    }
}
```

Is there a way to reference to the parent (& should be ul li)? Maybe even a mixin to solve it?

Comment: Can you show the desired CSS output? `&` simply repeats the selector created so far, including all nesting levels. There is no "go back to parent" in SCSS.

Comment: @connexo Sure. I want it to look like this: `ul li:first-child a { ... }` and also put inside the `a` element instead of above. But since I can't reuse `ul li` or reference it, it seems impossible.

Answer (score 0):

use like this. Do whatever you want to do with class `link`
and if you want anchor under anchor it is html validation error. you must avoid that.

```
ul {
  li {
    &.link {
      &:first-child {
        a {
          color: red;
        }
      }
      &:last-child {
        a {
          color: red;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Output

```
ul li.link:first-child a {
  color: red;
}
ul li.link:last-child a {
  color: red;
}
```